# Subsets Sum in array

Tags: vba, excel

I have nice code to get sum of subsets in Python:

```
# Python3 program to print sums of
# all possible subsets.

# Prints sums of all subsets of arr[l..r]
def subsetSums(arr, l, r, sum = 0):

    # Print current subset
    if l > r:
        print (sum, end = " ")
        return

    # Subset including arr[l]
    subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum + arr[l])

    # Subset excluding arr[l]
    subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum)

# Driver code
arr = [5.76, 4.45, 3.2]
n = len(arr)
subsetSums(arr, 0, n - 1)
```

How to do same thing in Excel VBA?

Comment: Where is name 'arr' defined btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Function subsetSums(arr As Variant, l As Long, r As Long, sum As Long)
    If l > r Then
        Debug.Print (sum)
        Exit Function
    End If
    'Subset including arr[l]
    a = subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum + arr(l))

    'Subset excluding arr[l]
    a = subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum)
End Function

Sub Driver()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array(1, 3, 5)
    a = subsetSums(arr, LBound(arr), UBound(arr), 0)
End Sub
```

In a code, `a` variable is used just to satisfy VBA syntax, when you call a function, its result must be assigned to a variable.

Comment: You don't need this dummy var `a`. Either use `call` or omit the parentheses (like you do for a `sub`)